# How to Reset for Loop Parameter with Timeout

Tags: javascript, for-loop, settimeout

I am trying to run a function every 10 ms and start the function over if a value reaches a certain threshold.

How can I start this for loop over again if `value > 10`?

```
let x = 0
let ln = 12

function getValue() {
  // Returns an integer value
}

for (x; x <= ln; x++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    getValue((value) => {
      if(value > 10) x = 0; // Restart for loop - doesn't seem to be working as intended
      if(x == 12) // do something else
    })
  }, 10)
}
```

Comment: what's your actual problem? doesn't `x = 0` reset the loop?

Comment: You're not going to be able to reset the loop from `setTimeout` the entire loop runs before the first timeout fires.

Comment: Is `getValue` asynchronous?

Comment: @MarkMeyer `getValue` is synchronous

Comment: @MarkMeyer is there a different way to achieve this in JS?

Comment: You have not defined getValue , neither you have invoked/called it.

Comment: @Avan it is a placeholder for a more elaborate function...

Comment: your `getValue` function doesn't do anything with the function you are passing to it.

Comment: @sid-m Yes, sorry, now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way to achieve something like this is with `setInterval`. Keep a counter that's incremented with each call to `setInterval()` if the counter reaches the limit, clear the interval with `clearInterval`. If it meets some other condition reset the counter back to zero:

```js
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 12, 4, 1, 2, 4, 6, 3]
let i = 0
function getValue(fn){
    fn(nums[i % nums.length])
    i++
}

const MAX_ITERATIONS = 10

let iteration = 0
let int = setInterval(() => {
    getValue((value) => {
        if(value > 10) iteration = 0; // Reset the counter
        else iteration++
    })
    console.log("loop iteration: ", iteration)
    if (iteration >= MAX_ITERATIONS) clearInterval(int)
}, 1000)
```

With a lower `MAX_ITERATIONS` it will reach the end of loop before getting a value greater than 10 the second time and stop:

```js
let nums = [1, 2, 3, 12, 4, 1, 2, 4, 6, 3]
let i = 0
function getValue(fn){
    fn(nums[i % nums.length])
    i++
}

const MAX_ITERATIONS = 4

let iteration = 0
let int = setInterval(() => {
    getValue((value) => {
        if(value > 10) iteration = 0; // Reset the counter
        else iteration++
    })
    console.log("loop iteration: ", iteration)
    if (iteration >= MAX_ITERATIONS) clearInterval(int)
}, 1000)
```

Comment: This runs 5 times and exits. I am looking for a behavior that would turn your array into an infinite loop, e.g. each time 12 is called the counter will start again 1, 2, 3, 12, 1, 2, 3, 12,1, 2, 3, 12...

Comment: @Matthew -- sorry, copy and paste error. I made `getValue` spit out looped values. As it is it will run forever because iterations gets reset before the counter runs out. But if you lower `MAX_ITERATIONS` it will quit.

Comment: This is close... I am trying to get a function that will 
1. Restart a for loop if a value in the array is ever greater than a threshold
2. Exit if no items in the array are greater than the threshold before `MAX_ITERATIONS` has been reached.

Comment: I think this answer is correct. I still need to wrap my head around some of the code though...

Comment: @Matthew. It is a little harder when to understand the async issues when dealing with timeouts and intervals. Basically this will keep calling `getValue` on a 1000ms schedule until `iteration>= MAX_ITERATIONS`. `iteration` can be set back to zero, which we do if `getValue` returns something greater than 10.

Comment: OK. I think this is exactly what I was hoping for. I will have to run a few more tests in the morning. Thanks for the help Mark!!